# Do I get Kerrigan levels if I replay a mission?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I am playing the campaign in Hard, and I cannot complete all optional objectives to get the `Kerrigan Levels` for a specific mission, can I replay it immediately upon finishing it but in Normal to try to complete everything and get them? Or only the first one counts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you missed some Kerrigan levels in earlier missions, you absolutely **can** go to the archives to replay those missions and any additional levels you gain will be counted towards your campaign total.

For example, let's say your current campaign progress is up to the Phantom of the Void mission, but you only received one Kerrigan level from the [Waking the Ancient mission](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108620/where-are-the-essences-for-the-bonus-objective-on-the-level-waking-the-ancients) (you can get a total of 3 via the bonus objective). You decide to replay the mission via the Archives and manage to get 2 Kerrigan levels out of the 3 that are available, you will gain **one** additional level to your total (as you already have 1 from the first playthrough). If you want the last level from the mission, you will need to replay the mission again and make sure this time to get all 3 essences in the mission.

There is only one caveat. When you replay a mission, the game will use the Kerrigan level accumulated up to the point of that mission in the campaign. Once you finish the replay and wish to proceed with the campaign again, you will need to go back to the Kerrigan screen and reselect the abilities that were unselected.

Comment: I missed 1 level while playing,  so when I hit 69 I whent back and got the level I missed, Kerrigan got to 70 but I did not get the achievement.

Comment: Are you sure this is not due to any other factors like disconnections or the like? I will remove that line for the time being, but I will test the achievement part of this answer later.

Comment: Yes, while redoing the mission I got an achievement I missed the first time.

Comment: No.. I meant the level 70 achievement... I think most of us have agreed that mission achievements are definitely obtainable during a replay.

Comment: My point was that achievements was not disabled because I got other achievements.

Comment: Oh I see. Well as I said, I've removed this from my answer and will keep investigating (as I haven't finished the campaign yet).

Comment: `...will use Kerrigan level appropriate for that mission...` - Does it still allow me to select girl's low-level abilities before replaying, or does the game just give me some setup it decides?

Comment: @OrcJMR Yes. On the replay screen, you get the opportunity to choose her abilities (that are available to her given the total number of levels she has up to that mission in the campaign). There is a button there that says "Kerrigan", you can't miss it. You can also change your swarm upgrades for your army too.

Comment: @Blem Looks like this is actually due to a bug. It is supposed to unlock. Take a look at these questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108991/why-didnt-i-earn-the-level-70-kerrigan-power-achievement and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108989/how-can-i-earn-achievements-i-got-while-achievements-were-disabled