# How can I earn achievements I completed while achievements were disabled?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

For some reason, Blizzard opted to disable achievements on launch day (or their achievement system broke). I said screw it, and powered through the campaign anyway. I hit level 70 while achievements were disabled, and now when I go back and replay the mission where I hit 70 in the archives, the achievement for hitting 70 won't unlock. Ditto for the achievement for doing all the evolution missions, and a couple others.

Is there some way I can get these through the archives? Can I get them if I restart the campaign entirely? Or is this like some of the achievements that you could get early in Diablo 3 where you just had to wait a couple weeks for Blizzard to get their sh*t together? Achievements are definitely working now, per a [community manager](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8197180684?page=11#214).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That was a server fault, not their decision.

While achievements were disabled, you did not *earn* any. (Plus "Kerrigan Power 70" may be broken on its own, as in "only awarded when you get it after the last level-awarding mission, not from archives".)

- All the level-specific achievements you can obtain by replaying missions from archives.
- Mutation achievement ticks when you swap a mutation for another one.
- For some achievements, like conversations, you will need to restart the campaign. "Abathur's Cookbook" also seems to be awarded at evolution choices themselves, which are not replayable.

As for now, Blizzard did not announce anything regarding fixing the achievements in HotS, so we have to assume it was a usual "just do it again later" server outage.

At least you can do Kerrigan Level 70 on Casual :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to just play and go through them again.  The achievements were up and down during the Launch Day.  For example, I got achievements for the first two missions I played, plus missions 6 and 7 but none of the rest lol.

I also had the Level 70 Kerrigan problem but I was able to do it by beating the campaign quickly on Casual.  That's the fastest way to do it and the only way to get the achievements is to replay it from scratch.  Since Kerrigan starts at level 1 to 70... it requires the whole campaign.  The rest which obtain to just a single mission, you need to redo the whole mission from scratch.

Obviously, you will need to redo part of it on Hard or Brutal for the Bonus Achievements or the 'Mastery Achievement'.