# Is replaying the final mission enough to finish the campaign, if half of my campaign was done offline?

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft 2, Heart of the Swarm.

So about halfway through the campaign, I begun having a terrible internet connection. So I finished most missions offline. Including the final mission.

Naturally, I didn't get the "Campaign Completed" achievement.

Now that my internet is fine again, I found a save file of the final mission, which was almost finished. So I loaded it and finished while properly connected to battle.net.

I was expecting to get the achievement, but I didn't. Actually, I didn't get any of the three possible achievements (and I should have).

I suppose that it is because the save file is of offline origin. So I plan to load the save file, go to the leviathan, and play the final mission on casual difficulty to just get the thing finished and get my damn achievement for once and for all. **Will this work? Considering that there are *other* campaign missions that were also completed during offline gameplay?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you will not get the achivement for completing the campaign at a certain level(Normal, Hard etc.), by only completing the final mission. In other words, your Battlenet will not reg. the completion of the campaign.
Completing the campaign is triggered by the individual sets of mission achivements (like getting the achivement for the Char set)

By completing all the sets, including the final set (Final Missions), you will the completion! So look through your achivements list, and see what sets you are missing.

TIP:
Complete the final mission, and load the other missions that you are missing, afterwards.

List of Mission sets from Sc2 HOTS:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/starcraft-2/Heart_of_the_Swarm_Walkthrough

Comment: So I literally have to finish everything online? Damn. I'll just rush through all of it on casual difficulty then.

Comment: You will have to complete each mission that you haven't got a "completion" from yea.

Comment: Thanks. I played those missions on casual and finally got the damn achievement :D.

Comment: Sounds good. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in WoL where you could load the final mission on brutal and get the campaign completed on brutal achievement (and the Kerrigan portrait that went with it). If they did not fix it (not sure if they did), it should work.

However, you will not get the achivements for doing "x" numbers of missions on the difficulty you chose. You will also not get the achievements for doing the missions you did offline as you did not have a B.Net connection when doing the missions.

This [thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108989/how-can-i-earn-achievements-i-completed-while-achievements-were-disabled) explains what happens when you lost connection to B.Net (as the acievements system went down on the launch day): [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108989/how-can-i-earn-achievements-i-completed-while-achievements-were-disabled)

Comment: Seriously? Completing the final WoL mission is enough to get Kerrigan's portrait? Damn. I played the whole thing for nothing?!

Comment: it was for a while, thats how my friend got the campaign on brutal acheivement, no idea if they fixed it.